# How to clean water spots from wooden table?

Tags: cleaning, wood

I have got water spots on my wooden table. Is there any trick to make them disappear.

Comment: A photograph would help. What kind of wood? Is the surface painted or varnished or just untreated wood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be surprising, but the best solution I've found to remove both water and heat spots from a wooden table, is an iron. Cover the spot with a dish towel (so as not to directly burn the table), then iron the towel. The heat will transfer from the towel to the wood and the spot will magically disappear. I have done this myself multiple times, and so has my mother.

This is a [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5AjjkTDAPQ) that I followed. Often the youtubers use thick towels, or folded a towel a bunch, but we found there wasn't enough heat being transferred. So just use a regular thickness towel, and don't fold it, but just keep an eye on it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To remove white rings left by wet glasses on wood furniture, mix equal parts vinegar and olive oil and apply it with a soft cloth while moving with the wood grain. Use another clean, soft cloth to shine it up. To get white water rings off leather furniture, dab them with a sponge soaked in full-strength white vinegar

*Steps for Removing Water Stains on Untreated Wood

1. Mix one teaspoon of salt with several drops of water to create a salt paste.
2. Apply the paste to the stained wood.
3. Use a clean, damp towel to gently rub the paste into the water marks.
4. Rub until the stain is no longer being removed.
5. Wipe the paste from the wood.

Answer (score 0):

Use any volatile liquid like any glass cleaner or you could also use alcohol or petrol. Volatile liquids evaporate at a much faster rate and hence unlike water do not leave stains.